# How to filter select using the value of other selects in the page Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Everyone, Please Help me. I have 5 select boxes that are coming from a json object. I want to filter the options or show an error if the user selects the same in any of the select boxes. I'm creating a basketball app where I want to select 5 players from the team and assign the unique role.

The first is the JSON Object That I'm fetching from. And second is the code I'm implementing to show the select elements. Users can select players from the dropdown maximum of 5 players can be selected out of any number and these player names and roles should be dependent on each selection to filter out.

[image]

```
const initialState = {
  team: [
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", id: 1, position: "Point Guard (PG)" },
    {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe2",
      id: 2,
      position: "Shooting Guard (SG)",
    },
    {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe3",
      id: 3,
      position: "Small Forward (SF)",
    },
    {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe4",
      id: 4,
      position: "Power Forward (PF)",
    },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe5", id: 5, position: "Center (C)" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe6", id: 6, position: "Center (C)" },
  ],
};
```

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { Context } from "./../Store";
import Styled from "styled-components";
import Select from "react-select";

const TeamsContainerStyled = Styled.div`

.select{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


`;

function FirstQuarter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
  const [team, setTeam] = useState(state.team);
  const [state1, setState1] = useState("");
  const [state2, setState2] = useState("");
  const [state3, setState3] = useState("");
  const [state4, setState4] = useState("");
  const [state5, setState5] = useState("");

  console.log(team, state1, state2);

  function changeHandler(evnt) {
    setState1(evnt.value);

    console.log(evnt);

  }

  return (
    <TeamsContainerStyled>
      {team.length >= 1 &&
        team.slice(0, 5).map(({ firstName, lastName, position }, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} className="select">
              <div className="PlayerName">
                <Select
                  options={team}
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                  getOptionLabel={(opt) => {
                    return `${opt.firstName} ${opt.lastName}`;
                  }}
                  getOptionValue={(opt) => opt.id}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="PlayerPosition">
                <input list="data1" type="text" value={position} />
                <datalist id="data1">
                  {team.map((el) => {
                    return <option value={el.position} />;
                  })}
                </datalist>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </TeamsContainerStyled>
  );
}

export default FirstQuarter;
```

Comment: Can you please post some code of what you've tried already, or better yet a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hello, I have just fetched from the json and the above screenshot represent that only.

Comment: I have added my code please check.

Comment: Anyone with a better solution